# Invalid conversion from throwing function type (_,_,_) throws to non-throwing function type (Data?, Response?, URLResponse?) Void

Tags: ios

I am new at Swift programming and I am getting an error on a "let task = URLSession. I have researched and found some of those errors but none of the answers worked for me. Here is my code and line 44 throws this error

```
import UIKit

class loginViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var userLoginTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userPasswordTextField: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func loginButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        let user_login = userLoginTextField.text;
        let user_passwd = userPasswordTextField.text;

        if((user_passwd?.isEmpty)! || (user_passwd?.isEmpty)!) { return; }

        //Send user data to server
        let myUrl = NSURL(string: "https://www.pcpusa.net/legacy/iOS/userLogin.php");
        var request = URLRequest(url: myUrl! as URL);
        request.httpMethod = "POST";

        let postString = "login=\(String(describing: user_login))&password=\(String(describing: user_passwd))";

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

        **let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){**
            data,response,error in
            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            var err: NSError?
            var json = try JSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .mutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary

            if let parseJSON = json {
                var resultValue:String = parseJSON["status"] as String!;
                print("result: \(resultValue)")

                if(resultValue=="Success")
                {

                    //Login is successful
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, value(forKey: "isUserLoggedIn"));
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();

                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil);

                }

            }

        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`URLSession.dataTask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1407613-datatask) expects a non-throwing completion handler and you are passing it a closure that throws. Because of this it fails to infer the method (in other words: it can’t find a method with that name that accepts a closure that throws).

To solve this you should catch and handle the errors that can happen when you decode the JSON.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new at this and do you know where I can find examples of the "catch".

Comment: See my answer below for an example of Swift's `do-try-catch` syntax.

Comment: The [Error Handling chapter of the Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html) would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

The key to that error message is "throwing function type". In Swift, whether or not a function can throw an error is part of its method signature. `URLSession` is expecting a closure/function that will **not** throw an error.

Therefore, if you throw an error, you must catch it.

So, you basically have two options here:

1. Wrap the throwable `try` in a `do-try-catch` block.
2. Use optionals to ignore possible errors and safely unwrap the result.

Example of option 1:

```
var json: [String: Any]!
do {
    json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any]
} catch let error { // `let error` is optional. It is the default.
    // Handle error here
}
```

Example of option 2:

(Also, I suggest using the `guard` statement for situations like this. This is my preferred method most of the time, and is considered by many to be more "Swifty")

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
    data,response,error in

    guard error != nil else {
        print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
        return
    }

    guard
        let data = data,
        let jsonObject = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers),
        let json = jsonObject as? [String: Any]
        else {
            print("Could not parse JSON")
            return
    }

    if let status = json["status"] as? String {
        print(status)
    }

}
```

**EDIT: Adds surrounding context to option 2.**

More on `guard`. It basically acts as an inside-out `if-else` statement.

You can use `guard` to test regular booleans. Or, like `if`, you can combine it with `let` to make a `guard-let` statement.

The difference between the two is:

- You use `if-let` when you say, "If this exists, I'll do something with it. Then I'll continue."
- You use `guard-let` when you say, "If I don't have this thing, then I can't continue".

Because of this, you must stop your function in its `else` statement, usually by returning or throwing an error (which you can't do here).

Comment: Where would the "guard" statement be inserted at on my code

Comment: I added more to context to my answer to show you where to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you `try` to decode (which can throw). Since you don't catch anywhere `URLSession.dataTask` complains because it doesn't expect that closure to throw. (If a method or closure can throw it will be marked with the `throws` keyword, this is an Apple provided method that does not have that keyword)

You just need to wrap in a `do` `catch` like so:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){ (data,response,error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
        return
    }

    var err: NSError?
    do {
        var json = try JSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .mutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary

        if let parseJSON = json {
            var resultValue:String = parseJSON["status"] as String!;
            print("result: \(resultValue)")
        ...
    } catch {
         //print("Error: unable to serialize data: \(err)")
    }
}
```